# Graph embedded in PyQt5 is black without showing anything

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I wanted to plot a graph in a PyQt5 window but it is completely black. I followed [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) and tried replacing my code with the `static_canvas` the author wrote, but its still black. Complete code works fine, the problem arises when I only keep a single graph.

My code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyp


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQT(Figure())
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        values = [i+1 for i in range(10)]
        axe = [i for i in range(10)]
        self.ax.plot(axe, values)
        # pyp.show() doesn't do anything


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Regardless of what I try to plot, the result is the same black window. What is the issue?

Also, how do I go about linking a function that plots something to the `FigureCanvasQT`? I want to embed a function from a different file to do and show the plot without having to write so much code in the window file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial that links FigureCanvasQT is not used but FigureCanvas. When analyzing the source code it is observed that FigureCanvasQT is FigureCanvas but when exporting(see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L1023)) it as _Backend more properties are added. So the solution is to change to:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas

# ...
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote `FigureCanvasQT` because `FigureCanvas` did not appear in the suggestions by PyCharm so I assumed its name was changed since the example was posted. Also, how do I go about linking a method from an imported class to PyQt to place the plots?